# VBA - Leave Do Until when specific row is reached

Tags: vba, excel

In my VBA Code i go from the last row in my table to the top of my table. But i want that the Do Until Loop ends when it reached Row 10.

Right now I am using this Do Until Loop:

```
Do 
    ' Do Something
Loop Until ActiveCell.Address = "$N$10:$BI$10"
```

How do i have to change my code that it will stop when it reached row 10?

Comment: @QHarr i added the rest of the code

Comment: @QHarr i changed the question so that it maybe gets clear what i want. All the rest of my VBA Code works fine. The only problem i have, is that the do loop won´t stop when it reaches row 10

Comment: Loop Until ActiveCell.Row = 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming rest of code is correct use:

```
Loop Until ActiveCell.Row = 10
```

If that fails you problem is logic in other parts of your code ie. ActiveCell never reaches row 10.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question in more theoretical fashion. There are multiple ways of exiting `Do` loops in VBA.

1. **The proper way**

   1.1.  **While or Until at the begining**

   This checks the condition first, if the condition is met, it enters the loop and repeat with the condition being met at the start of every loop.

   ```
   Do While i <= 5
     '#code here
   Loop
   ```

   *These two are equivalent.*

   ```
   Do Until i > 5
     '#code here
   Loop
   ```

   1.2. **While or until at the end**

   This is almost the same as what is described above. The only difference being, with sole `Do` statement at the beginning, your code-block always gets executed at least once! This can be particularly useful, when you want to execute something at least once, but don't want it to  repeat unless a condition is met.

   ```
   Do 
     '#code here
   Loop While i <= 5
   ```

   or

   ```
   Do 
     '#code here
   Loop Until i > 5
   ```
2. **The enforced way**
   You can exit out of any loop, including `Do` with the so called `Exit` statement. This escapes the currently ongoing `Do` loop upon reaching the statement *no questions asked*. While you usually should try to avoid using the `Exit` statement, as in majority of cases it is possible to avoid using it with a proper condition at the `While` or `Until` portion of your code, it can come in handy in some cases.

   Additionally, keep in mind, inside nested `Do` loops, `Exit` always exits only the innermost loop. This means, this would exit only the loop inside and let the others run, acting as a weird form of `Continue`

   ```
   Do While (handler = True)
      Do
         '# execute me
          If weird_condition = True Then
              Exit Do
              ' i return to the "handler" loop
          End If
          field = field + 1 
      Loop Until field = field_amount
   Loop
   ```
3. **The not so nice enforced way**

   Alternatively, you can stop the entire exution, with the `Stop` statement. I would strongly advise against doing this, but technically it is a possibility so I'm listing it here. Similarly like `End` it ends the execution, but unlike `End` (eg. `End Sub`), it does not close any files or clear any variables - so technically this means you could use it to exit a loop. I would however recommend simply using the `Exit` statement instead. Can't really think of a case when I would ever use this.